# How to pick a model based on AIC and number of factors?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, aic, glmm

I'm trying to create a linear mixed model for some of my data. I'm brute forcing a backwards step selection by taking out the least significant parameter both times. I went back 6 fixed effects and that's about where I decided to stop. I ended up with an output like this (I only included fixed effects just for ease of reading):

```
Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 8.648e-01  4.816e-01 6.909e+02   1.796 0.072993 .  
LagAir      3.006e-01  4.191e-02 9.129e+00   7.172 4.87e-05 ***
Precip      5.811e-03  2.467e-03 3.770e+00   2.355 0.082033 .  
Elevation   6.829e-03  1.757e-03 1.111e+03   3.887 0.000107 ***
```

To me, that seems like a pretty good and simplified model, yet the AIC value is 2420. The thing is that the AIC value of the full model, 2190, would suggest it's the better model right? But those effects are almost overwhelming...

```
Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.146e+00  4.248e-01  9.987e+01   2.698 0.008202 ** 
AirTemp       1.291e-01  7.179e-02  7.819e+00   1.798 0.110740    
LagAir        1.768e-01  5.207e-02  7.822e+00   3.394 0.009758 ** 
Radiation     1.461e-02  2.826e-02  8.859e+00   0.517 0.617807    
Windspeed     1.158e-02  2.157e-02  9.018e+00   0.537 0.604238    
LagRadiation -2.283e-02  1.911e-02  9.360e+00  -1.195 0.261553    
Precip        2.056e-03  3.326e-03  6.029e+00   0.618 0.559023    
RainingTRUE   1.601e-02  5.537e-02  8.619e+00   0.289 0.779305    
LULC81        8.024e-02  2.318e-02  1.958e+03   3.461 0.000549 ***
LULC42       -1.652e-01  2.513e-02  2.123e+03  -6.575 6.12e-11 ***
LULC22       -2.403e-02  1.861e-01  3.388e+03  -0.129 0.897274    
LULC43        6.082e-02  2.460e-02  2.299e+03   2.473 0.013480 *  
Elevation     5.756e-03  1.538e-03  9.849e+01   3.742 0.000307 ***
```

I don't necessarily need someone to walk through my code, but I just need guidance ASAP about how to decide which model to use. I thought a smaller number of effects was better.

If you want to see my data, here it is:

```
> dput(head(test_data, 100))
structure(list(LogHR = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.02347550491101, 
2.4923232453905, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.27447055729729, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.57083507949072, NaN, NaN, 2.96761722360037, 
NaN, 3.33630324174417, NaN, 2.77770498680894, 3.77351697406649, 
NaN, 3.69894834229534, 3.52276214644725, 3.63480008925141, 3.82694876915115, 
3.64885401725737, 3.52484761604103, 3.49319703721802, 3.67697656158564, 
3.53373853416072, 3.41430323466502, 3.22897597948073, 3.34585884026112, 
3.27880724961631, 3.22502421803497, 2.96236092612278, 3.07884472627376, 
3.02851451570309, 2.98437283203721, 2.67584548484876, 2.82100778581387, 
2.90456810382633, 2.7224195764621, 2.84007036906842, 2.71117708507883, 
2.62590140681403, 2.56665917693804, 2.63056350183205, 2.46992329113931, 
2.53839185961721, 2.46628432565991, 2.60077080854007, 2.27421853974114, 
2.18830603622712, 3.0098013384877, 2.8304902279741, NaN, 2.67705751801136, 
2.22946048333475, 2.91430907177012, 2.271830481057, NaN, 2.42670180627851, 
2.31918324503405, 2.1809958228087, 2.19019250274665, 3.19322278121153
), AirTemp = c(-1.61103364278686, -1.66486398863998, -1.54374571047046, 
-1.514908025192, -1.62256871689824, -1.73984197036397, -1.66294147628808, 
-1.72830689625259, -1.77252468034623, -1.83789010031073, -1.88210788440437, 
-1.85327019912591, -1.73984197036397, -1.6494838898248, -1.57066088339702, 
-1.45338762993129, -1.5168305375439, -1.56489334634133, -1.6514064021767, 
-1.68216659980706, -1.68024408745516, -1.62641374160204, -1.55912580928563, 
-1.47645777815405, -1.39186723467057, -1.39763477172627, -1.38417718526299, 
-1.33226935176176, -1.25344634533397, -1.18231338831378, -1.07465269660753, 
-1.00351973958733, -0.947766881382312, -0.905471609640573, -0.820881066157095, 
-0.774740769711561, -0.703607812691363, -0.611327219800296, -0.501744015742153, 
-0.367168151109346, -0.174916915919623, 0.0115667822144094, 0.148065159199113, 
0.249958313849667, 0.430674474928007, 0.56140531485702, 0.667143494211368, 
0.740198963583463, 0.765191624158127, 0.84016960588212, 0.878619852920064, 
0.870929803512475, 0.932450198773187, 0.990125569330104, 1.04011089047943, 
0.988203056978207, 1.09009621162876, 1.1343139957224, 1.14969409453757, 
1.10163128574014, 1.13623650807429, 1.18237680451983, 1.17853177981603, 
1.14777158218568, 1.23428463802105, 1.24389719978054, 1.26119981094761, 
1.22851710096536, 1.24389719978054, 1.25543227389192, 1.22659458861346, 
1.22274956390967, 1.16891921805655, 1.11893389690722, 1.10355379809204, 
1.09394123633256, 0.968977933459234, 0.780571722973305, 0.565250339560814, 
0.351851468500221, 0.178825356829469, 0.0884672762902993, 0.0154118069182044, 
-0.0807138106766575, -0.259507459403101, -0.346020515238477, 
-0.359478101701758, -0.486363916926975, -0.555574361595276, -0.494053966334564, 
-0.542116775131995, -0.576721997466145, -0.605559682744604, -0.622862293911679, 
-0.665157565653418, -0.745903084433102, -0.829918469121882, -0.772818257359664, 
-0.958914535979231, -0.899704072584881), LagAir = c(-1.49518745179209, 
-0.109267786452063, -1.67203156997695, -1.55093179339384, -1.522098513255, 
-1.62974275910666, -1.74699809833792, -1.67010935130103, -1.73546478628239, 
0.171376140232603, -1.84503125080996, -1.88924228035618, -1.86040900021734, 
-0.78012210434897, -1.65665382056957, -1.57784285485675, -1.46058751562549, 
-1.52402073193093, -1.57207619882899, -1.65857603924549, -1.68933153806025, 
-1.68740931938433, -1.6335871964585, -1.56630954280122, -1.48365413973656, 
-1.39907651799597, -1.40484317402374, -1.39138764329228, -1.33948773904238, 
-1.26067677332956, -1.18955468232043, -1.08191043646878, -1.01078834545965, 
-0.955044003857905, -0.912755192987613, -0.828177571247029, -0.782044323024892, 
-0.710922232015764, -0.618655735571491, -0.509089271043916, -0.37453396372935, 
-1.7796758158286, 0.00414311542735651, 0.140620641417845, 0.242498231241731, 
0.423186786778433, 0.553897656741155, 0.659619683916884, 0.732663993601935, 
0.757652836388925, 0.832619364749898, 0.871063738268345, 0.863374863564656, 
0.924885861194172, 0.982552421471842, 1.03253010704582, 0.98063020279592, 
1.08250779261981, 1.12671882216602, 1.1420965715734, 1.09404110467534, 
1.12864104084194, 1.17477428906408, 1.17092985171223, 1.14017435289748, 
1.22667419331398, 1.23628528669359, 1.2535852547769, 1.22090753728622, 
1.23628528669359, 1.24781859874913, 1.21898531861029, 1.21514088125845, 
1.16131875833262, 1.11134107275864, 1.09596332335126, 1.08635222997165, 
0.961408016036696, 0.773030585796304, 0.557742094092999, 0.344375821065616, 
-1.74699809833792, 0.0810318624642517, 0.00798755277920185, -0.0881233810169166, 
-0.266889717877697, -0.353389558294204, -0.366845089025661, -0.493711521636537, 
-0.562911393969742, -0.501400396340226, -0.549455863238286, -0.584055799404888, 
-0.612889079543723, -0.630189047627025, -0.672477858497317, -0.809398910098875, 
-0.753211042886056, 0.203206241041648, 0.242498231241731), Radiation = c(-0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.721769590845183, -0.717883214459192, -0.698451332529236, 
-0.651814815897342, -0.589632793721484, -0.492473384071705, -0.37588209249197, 
-0.278722682842191, -0.232086166210297, -0.119381251016553, -0.10772212185858, 
0.0283010516511109, 0.210960741792696, 0.242051752880625, 0.35864304446036, 
0.735621553901503, 0.821121834393308, 1.20975947299242, 1.51289683109974, 
1.7499657906452, 2.24742196805206, 2.34458137770184, 2.33680862492986, 
2.48837730398352, 2.56221845531735, 2.62440047749321, 2.66326424135312, 
2.72933263991497, 2.74487814545893, 2.77596915654686, 2.713787134371, 
2.73710539268695, 2.73710539268695, 2.69435525244105, 2.65160511219515, 
2.63217323026519, 2.64383235942316, 2.45728629289559, 2.42230890542167, 
2.34069500131585, 1.83935244752299, 1.99480750296264, 2.02978489043656, 
1.7460794142592, 1.60228348797753, 1.42351017422194, 1.07373629948273, 
1.12037281611463, 0.918281244043087, 0.743394306673485, 0.556848240145909, 
0.362529420846351, 0.172096977932784, -0.0844038635426328, -0.302040941158138, 
-0.601291922879457, -0.651814815897342, -0.686792203371263, -0.721769590845183, 
-0.733428720003157, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148), 
    Windspeed = c(-1.5432892339893, -1.18997289317795, -0.848219632611328, 
    -1.05828225705735, -1.44436065856212, -1.3769093571345, -1.13344227864813, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.32487549603319, -1.19061528652488, -1.11417047824024, 
    -0.856570746121415, -0.687621295878894, -0.703681129552137, 
    -0.814815178570982, -0.736443190245554, -0.777556364449057, 
    -0.904107853794215, -1.03258652318016, -1.47712271925554, 
    -1.35185601660424, -1.29404061538056, -0.828947832203436, 
    -0.822523898734138, -1.35249840995117, -1.28440471517662, 
    -1.21566862705514, -1.28440471517662, -1.08462038428147, 
    -1.26127855468715, -1.20988708693277, -0.956784108242453, 
    -0.817384751958701, -0.89190238020255, -0.511605518820146, 
    -0.606679734165747, -0.413961730086826, -0.407537796617529, 
    -0.432591137147789, -0.591904687186363, -0.679270182368807, 
    -0.644580941634602, -0.239230739721938, -0.402398649842091, 
    -0.150580457845635, -0.577772033553909, -0.198117565518435, 
    0.112158421048627, 0.0960985873753839, 0.284319838025797, 
    0.59266864455207, 0.612582838306892, -0.054863849153104, 
    0.553482650389356, 0.261193677536326, 0.423076800962619, 
    -0.622097174492061, -0.00796913482723329, 0.121794321252573, 
    0.588814284470491, -0.311821187924998, 0.0247929258661831, 
    0.611298051613032, -0.457644477678049, 0.488600922349452, 
    -0.246939459885095, 0.312585145290705, 0.219438109985893, 
    -0.252078606660533, 0.0639789200288969, 0.133357401497308, 
    -0.451862937555681, 0.265690430964834, 0.482176988880155, 
    -0.410107370005248, -0.901538280406496, -0.343298461924555, 
    -1.43472475835818, -1.49189776623492, -1.50924238660203, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.54014119191596, -1.5432892339893, -1.54014119191596, -1.5432892339893
    ), LagRadiation = c(-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.721769590845183, -0.717883214459192, -0.698451332529236, 
    -0.651814815897342, -0.589632793721484, -0.492473384071705, 
    -0.37588209249197, -0.278722682842191, -0.232086166210297, 
    -0.119381251016553, -0.10772212185858, 0.0283010516511109, 
    0.210960741792696, 0.242051752880625, 0.35864304446036, 0.735621553901503, 
    0.821121834393308, 1.20975947299242, 1.51289683109974, 1.7499657906452, 
    2.24742196805206, 2.34458137770184, 2.33680862492986, 2.48837730398352, 
    2.56221845531735, 2.62440047749321, 2.66326424135312, 2.72933263991497, 
    2.74487814545893, 2.77596915654686, 2.713787134371, 2.73710539268695, 
    2.73710539268695, 2.69435525244105, 2.65160511219515, 2.63217323026519, 
    2.64383235942316, 2.45728629289559, 2.42230890542167, 2.34069500131585, 
    1.83935244752299, 1.99480750296264, 2.02978489043656, 1.7460794142592, 
    1.60228348797753, 1.42351017422194, 1.07373629948273, 1.12037281611463, 
    0.918281244043087, 0.743394306673485, 0.556848240145909, 
    0.362529420846351, 0.172096977932784, -0.0844038635426328, 
    -0.302040941158138, -0.601291922879457, -0.651814815897342, 
    -0.686792203371263, -0.721769590845183, -0.733428720003157, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, 
    -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148), Precip = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Raining = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), LULC = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("41", "81", 
    "42", "22", "43"), class = "factor"), Elevation = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 282.51, NA, NA, 
    NA, 282.76, NA, NA, NA, 281.96, NA, NA, NA, 282.07, NA, NA, 
    NA, 282.07, NA, NA, NA, 281.5, NA, NA, NA, 283.78, NA, NA, 
    NA, 283.16, NA, NA, NA, 284.22, NA, NA, NA, 284.46, NA, NA, 
    NA, 284.22, NA, NA, NA, 283.77, NA, NA, NA, 284.28, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Turtle = c("R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
    "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    Turtle = c("R3L1", "R3L12"), .rows = structure(list(c(97L, 
    99L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
    37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
    49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
    61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
    73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
    85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
    98L, 100L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Don't mind the NAs in the Heart Rate column, that is just for when the biologger didn't catch any data.

I'm pretty new to this when compared to many people on this website, so please explain things in an easy way! Nothing too complicated.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question?  Does it indicate you resolved that one?

Comment: @whuber my other question is with glmm

Comment: That distinction is not evident.  Here, you don't even tell us what model you are fitting.

Comment: @whuber the model isn't necessarily important. I'm more asking the best process for picking a model in general (AIC, BIC, p-value, biological significance)

Comment: That's extremely broad -- have you looked at some of our threads on [model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=model+selection)? They might help answer your question or suggest effective ways to narrow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Model Comparison

Your assumption about AIC/BIC criterion is correct, in that lower values are associated with better representations of your model. However, AIC tends to be more liberal and biased towards more complicated models, and sometimes these values will have opposite values across models. These values typically don't differ dramatically, but if they do, it may point to issues with estimating complexity. [Here is a good read on the topic](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-25/issue-3/To-Explain-or-to-Predict/10.1214/10-STS330.full)  if you are interested in learning more (I believe discussion starts around Page 12).

It is hard to tell based off the information provided if your random effects here are the same for both models. I suspect they are, which would make your models nested, and would therefore allow the use of a likelihood ratio test (LRT) to directly compare the models if your AIC/BIC values do not clearly show a better candidate model. The LRT statistic is formed as twice the log of the ratio of the likelihood of the more complex (larger) model divided by the likelihood of the less complex (smaller) model.

##### Worked Example

I've fit two models with the `carrots` data from the lmerTest package below to demonstrate. Notice that I have fit them with ML as comparing models with REML isn't wise.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lmerTest)

#### Fit Model 1 ####
fit.1 <- lmer(Preference 
              ~ sens2  
              + (1 + sens2 | Consumer),
              data=carrots,
              REML = FALSE)

#### Fit Model 2 ####
fit.2 <- lmer(Preference 
            ~ sens2 
            + Homesize 
            + (1 + sens2 | Consumer),
            data=carrots,
            REML = FALSE)

#### LRT Test ####
anova(fit.1,fit.2)
```

The `anova` function will give a summary like this, which includes the AIC/BIC of both models and a p value which highlights if the more complex model is a better candidate:

```
Data: carrots
Models:
fit.1: Preference ~ sens2 + (1 + sens2 | Consumer)
fit.2: Preference ~ sens2 + Homesize + (1 + sens2 | Consumer)
      npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
fit.1    6 3752.2 3782.9 -1870.1   3740.2                       
fit.2    7 3748.7 3784.5 -1867.4   3734.7 5.4885  1    0.01914 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

We can see here that `fit.2` is significant and may be preferred over the simpler model. Notice the AIC is lower in the second model and the BIC is higher in the second model, which would make comparison between the two a bit confusing using these criterion. Here an LRT test may be preferred since it is difficult to ascertain which model is "better" off the AIC/BIC criterion alone. Since this may be a bit confusing, [this paper](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00063.x) is another useful guide for reading about these methods.

##### Final Note

Keep in mind that stepwise selection of models is generally not a great practice. It is better to generate a model based off theory, and if your predictors do not show significance or are redundant, it is best to leave them in so your model is tested. You can only dictate that Model A and Model B are comparable if you have provided a clear theoretical rationale for doing so, or there are strong data-driven reasons for selecting another model (such as Model A not converging).

Comment: I had tried the LRT but I was always confused what the significant p-value meant - thanks!! Very useful information, I'll look into the biological significance of my models as well.